# Making Vertical Gradient, then make top half transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, transparency

So, I would like to make this texture to where I have the gradient going from top to bottom, instead of side to side like in the picture. After that, I would like to make the top half, lets just say, the purple, transparent. I am using cycles renderer in blender v2.76.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!
Danny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two things: texture coordinates and a way to control them. The Vector Mapping will allow you to place the gradient texture where you need it. Then you can use multiple color ramps to mix color and a transparent shader.

[image]

Blend File

[image]