# How to make an object fade out from one end?

Tags: materials, transparency

I've been trying to make an object fade from one end in cycles, sort of like a gradient of transparency. I was wondering of anyone could help.
Here is an example of what I want to achieve in terms of transparency:

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have done so far in an attached image and words.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in terms of your end goal? Are you trying to animate something that goes from solid to transparent? Are you trying to make a still shot do this? This will affect the quality of the answer you get.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45866/making-vertical-gradient-then-make-top-half-transparent

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/how-to-make-one-object-gradually-disappear-as-it-passes-through-another-object

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object as mapping coordinate for a coloramp, and by moving it around you can tune up the effect or transparency which is obtained by mixing a transparent and a diffuse shader in this case. Just an example.
[image]

You can also use the generated mapping coordinate depending on your geometry. In the last picture i had put the object used for mapping a little backward in the scene. Here the input is a texture coordinate node and the mapping is slided on x
[image]

Comment: I find this image confusing. Making the object stand out from the background would help clarifying your answer