# Make object transparent only on bottom

Tags: transparency

I have a hat object, and I want to make most of the bottom transparent. I'm making an app where a user can place a hat on their head. However, if I place the hat in the correct position, and the camera angle is from the bottom, the hat will block the users face.

I've downloaded other objects that had transparency only in certain areas, which could only be seen from certain angles, but I don't know how to create this on an existing object.

I attached a screenshot of the area I would like to make transparent.

Thanks!

[image: Hat to be edited]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This can be easily achieved by assigning different materials (transparent and opaque) to different parts of your hat. [The process is described in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/78972).

Comment: Thanks! I followed the answers you linked with no success. I created a new material while the area is selected, and tried making the alpha 0.0. Also, I made the surface Glass/Transparent/Translucent, but none of them work either. I'm also very new to Blender, is there a step-by-step example of doing this? Thanks again!

Comment: Hello again :). Alpha set to zero is enough. Just make sure to set your material's Blending mode to *Alpha Blend*. I posted a full answer for you.

Comment: related: [making vertical gradient then make top half transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45866)